# How do I get the name of a test being run from within a setup or teardown callback?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing

I'd like to add performance warnings to our tests, like so:

```
# in test_helper.rb
class ActiveSupport::TestCase
  def record_test_start_time
    @test_start_time = Time.now
  end
  setup :record_test_start_time

  def warn_long_running_test
    running_time = Time.now - @test_start_time
    if running_time > 10.seconds
      puts "WARNING: Test #{test_name} ran for #{running_time}"
    end
  end
  setup :record_test_start_time
end
```

How do I get the test name into the test_name variable?  I've had poor results using Kernel#caller from setup/teardown callbacks in the past.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **name** method gives you a string "*method name(class name)*" and I think @method_name gives you the name of the current test.

Answer (score 3):

At the moment, it's the method `method_name`.